# Iterate through rooms for a given socket

Tags: socket.io

I want to ensure my clients are only able to join a single room. To do this, I want to iterate through socket.rooms on the server and call leave for each room. Something like below:

```
//Pseudo code//
for each room in socket.rooms {
    socket.leave(room)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(socket.rooms).forEach(function(roomName){
    socket.leave(roomName) // this removes user from all of the existing rooms 
});
```

here, we get the room's the client is in by running a array, then remove him from all the rooms from the loop

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I assume because all sockets automatically join a default room identified by the socket ID, you only want to ignore the first room in the list and only leave any subsequent rooms ?

Comment: Kind of. I wanted to kick the user out all existing rooms before joining them in another. So i assume i just called socket.leave(roomName) in your above example and remove the condition statement.

Answer (score 0):

Socket io rooms are kept as sets so you should use `Array.from()`. Example

```
 Array.from(socket.rooms).forEach((roomId) => {
      socket.leave(roomId);
 });
```